# Float parsing in C#

Tags: c#, parsing, tryparse

In C# I declared an array of float in main()

```
float[] notas = new float[8];
```

Called the method and passed the array by reference also in main()

```
PopulateArray(ref notas);
```

Here's the implementation of the method PopulateArray(ref float[] arr1)

```
static void PopulateArray(ref float[] arr1)
    {
        bool vakid;

        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                do
                {
                    Console.Write($"Insira nota {i + 1}  ==>");
                    vakid = float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr1[i]);
                    if ((arr1[i] > 20.0) || (arr1[i] < 0.0))
                    {
                        Console.Write("\n\n\t\tAs notas só vão de 0 a 20\n\nPrima uma tecla para continuar");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                    Console.Clear();

                }while (!((arr1[i] <= 20) && (arr1[i] >= 0)));

            } while (!vakid); 
        }


    }
```

Used two loops, one to assure that the value inputed is between [0, 20] and another to ensure that whatever input is a decimal number (float). Before this implementation, the array **notas** was of **integer** and everything was working just fine, only **integers** were allowed and also in between the interval of [0, 20]. When I decided to change the type of data to **float**, whenever I type a decimal number (i.e. 3.0) it doesn't go through the outter loop, like if I were typing a character other than a number, much in the same way as when I type a letter.
So how can I type decimal numbers to store in my array? Ty

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean by "it doesn't go through the outter loop".  You have three nested loops.  Which isn't doing what you expect?  When you step through in a debugger, where specifically does the code first do something unexpected?

Comment: What locale (international number format settings) is in effect on your computer?

Comment: It's worth noting that the `ref` keyword isn't needed here.  Arrays are objects in c# and are passed by reference.  The `ref` keyword would only be needed if you wanted to change the reference in the calling method, which you aren't doing.

Comment: @David, true there are 3 loops. When I mention 2 I mean the 2 that serve as validation. If I type an integer (i.e. 13) between [0, 20] that value is stored in the array notas but if I type 13.0 that value it's not stored and so the execution is "trapped" on the outer do/while. Went through the debugger but honestly I've been away from programming for a long time. The only thing I can see is that if I type a decimal number that number it is not stored in the array.

Comment: @BenVoigt wish I could tell you that but I have got no clue. Where can I see that information?

Comment: Do **not** ignore the valid variable.  Finish your SO profile so we can see where you live, my crystal ball says that you need to type "3,0", comma instead of period.  You can see it from your grocery bill.

Comment: @Amy the ref keyword is needed because I'm assigning values to the array via a method. In C an array name is a pointer to the first index position of an array, honestly I don't know if in C# they work in the same way.

Comment: @mxajd You are assigning values to the array.  You are not assigning a new array reference.  The `ref` keyword is **not** needed.

Comment: @HansPassant is it? I read an article before posting the question and yes I read someone talking about the comma ','. I trully thought that it was some kind of a bad joke. I'm not familiar with c# language but everyother language I worked with used the decimal point.

Comment: @HansPassant you were right. Thank you so much, it works with the ',' though I find it a bit odd. Never the less thank you. Is there a way to choose tour comment as the right answer to my question?

Comment: @mxajd: Whether the decimal separator is `.` or `,` is one of those international number format settings I asked you about.  Here's an explanation how to find them (and, if you like, change them): https://superuser.com/q/969078/29943

Comment: Or you can tell just your program to ignore them, using `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;`

Answer (score 3):

I propose this alternative implementation :

```
static void PopulateArray(float[] arr1)
{

    for (int i = 1; i <= arr1.Length; i++)
    {
        float nota;

        Console.Write($"Insira nota {i}  ==> \n");

        while(! float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out nota) || nota > 20.0f || nota < 0 )
        {
           // Bad input message
            Console.Write("\n\n\t\tAs notas só vão de 0 a 20\n\nPrima uma tecla para continuar");
        }

        arr1[i] = nota;
    }
}
```

Note that **you don't need to pass the array by reference.** It's a reference type, so a copy of the reference is passed and the method can work on it.

Comment: Thank you. Really liked your purpose, it's very "clean" if I may say so. Just explained to another user that I've been away from programming for more than 5 years now. Just by raeding the comments and the answers it's kind of coming back to me now. Thank you so much

Answer (score 2):

Culture issue aside (decimal separator of `.` vs `,`), I'd get rid of one of the do loops like this:

```
    static void PopulateArray(float[] arr1)
    {
        bool vakid;
        for (int i = 0; i < arr1.Length; i++)
        {
            do
            {
                Console.Write($"Insira nota {i + 1}  ==>");
                vakid = float.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out arr1[i]);
                if (vakid)
                {
                    if ((arr1[i] > 20.0) || (arr1[i] < 0.0))
                    {
                        vakid = false;
                        Console.Write("\n\n\t\tAs notas só vão de 0 a 20\n\nPrima uma tecla para continuar");
                        Console.ReadKey();
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.Write("\n\n\t\tInvalid Entry\n\nPrima uma tecla para continuar");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                }                 
                Console.Clear();
            } while (!vakid);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Belive me I did try to get rid of one of the loops, most likely my control expression wasn't right. What I did was to agreggate all 3 conditions (as they are in the code) in one expression but now I realize that a number cannot be simultaneously smaller than 0 and greater than 20. It really show that I've been away from programming for more than 5 years now. Thank you for your input